# Joomla output override not working

Tags: php, joomla

Does anybody know why an output override won't work?
I am familiar with output override and have tried it before, but this time it wont work.
I am trying to override an article category blog layout, so I copied

> \components\com_content

and paste it to my template, inside "html" folder which I just made

```
\templates\my_teamplate\html\com_content
```

I edited

```
\templates\my_teamplate\html\com_content\views\category\tmpl\blog.php
```

and it won't work, I tried editing the original core, to make sure it's the correct file

```
\components\com_content\views\category\tmpl\blog.php
```

and it worked, im pretty sure, it's the correct file, I just dont know the reason why it's not overriding.
My Joomla version is 1.5.26

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML override does not mirror the component's exact folder structure.

Its default structure is:

> component/view/template.php

In your case:

> templates/yourTemplate/html/com_content/category/blog.php

### Edit

I am extending the example and adding the path for modules as well, in case anyone needs it:

**Component:**

The Joomla path to the original component view's template that you want to override:

```
/component/[componentName]/views/[viewName]/tmpl/[templateName].php
```

gets overridden by this file in your template:

```
/templates/[yourTemplate]/html/[componentName]/[viewName]/[templateName].php
```

**Module:**

The Joomla path to the original module's template that you want to override:

```
/module/[moduleName]/tmpl/[templateName].php
```

gets overridden by this file in your template:

```
/templates/[yourTemplate]/html/[moduleName]/[templateName].php
```

Comment: omg thanks, i am not aware of it's default structure
component/view/template.php
i thought all i have to do is just copy and paste the specific component folder(com_content). yes it it is indeed in a different path the original component has, "view" folder and "tmpl"
it's path is 
html/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php
thanks for the help, i really thought output overrides is not yet implemented in joomla 1.5

Comment: Glad to hear this helped. If the issue is resolved, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure should be

templates/template_name/html/com_content/category/blog.php